# How get a result from checkbox javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony

I want change a `radioBox` to `checkBox` for multiple choice.

My checkbox is:

```
<input id="ser-price" name="price" class="w3-check" value="Serviceable {{ price.getServiceablePrice }}" type="checkbox">
```

I changed it but always it take one value. This following my function by `Javascript` because I did a `block javascript` in the file `HTML.Twig`:

```
function closeWindowAndShowAlert(f) {

    var radios = document.getElementsByName('price');
    var price;
    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {                
            price = radios[i].value;

            break;
        } else {
            price = null;
        }
    }
    var priceChosen = document.getElementById("priceChosen").value;
    if (!price && !priceChosen) {
        alert("Please choose a price");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("This article has been successfully added to the cart");
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I correct my function to make me choice multi-choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to initialize your price with 0 and add the values in it:

```
var price = 0;
```

and in the loop you have to use `+=` to add to last added value:

```
price += +radios[i].value; // + prefix will convert the string to numbers
// break; // <---i guess this isn't required
```

Comment: May be `price += +radios[i].value;`

Comment: @Rayon got it...:)

Comment: I tested it, always take one choice, and when I delete break it display the message alert("Please choose a price");

Comment: i guess you should also remove the else part from the above one. @vero

Comment: Ok I remove it and I tested if the checkbox is selected , it display this message [object HTMLInputElement]  ;

Comment: You can do it like [this(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/uyc7u9kz/1/), just extract that function from event listener.